# How to send and receive email with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, smtp

I'm attempting to develop an endpoint in my REST API that receives user questions and forwards them to my email address. However, I encountered some errors.

I've configured the application.properties file with the following properties:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=myEmailAdress@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=MyAppPassword
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

here's the email service class:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender emailSender;

    public String sendSimpleMessage(String from, String to, String subject, String text) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom(from);
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);
        emailSender.send(message);

        return "Thank you for reporting your problem. We'll get back to you soon";
    }
}
```

and here's the rest api code:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmailController {

    private EmailService emailService;
    @PostMapping("/support")
    public String sendEmail(@RequestBody EmailDTO email) {
        MyUser user = (MyUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        return emailService.sendSimpleMessage(
                "example@gmail.com",
                "example@gmail.com",
                email.getSubject(),
                email.getMessage());
    }
}
```

here's the error:

```
 nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect] with root cause
```

i configured Mercury (smtp relay) as follow:
[image]
and i got a new error:

```
; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: jakarta.mail.MessagingException: 554 Shunned connection - only the QUIT command will be accepted.
] with root cause

jakarta.mail.MessagingException: 554 Shunned connection - only the QUIT command will be accepted.
```

Comment: The initial "connection refused" usually means that no server is listening on that port. Do you really have a SMTP server running on localhost at port 25? Double check your SMTP relay configuration, or drop the relay, if you can, at least for a test email. I don't understand why you have google settings in application.properties when you want to use a proxy.

Comment: If you examine the latest error, you'll notice that I received a new message following the activation of Mercury. If I'm utilizing Mercury as an SMTP relay in my application, what adjustments should I make in my application.properties file?